# How to change font-family for fusion chart on IE11

Tags: css, fusioncharts

Why is font-family not working on IE11? My fusion chart using font 'Source Sans Pro', its work on chrome perfectly, but not in IE11. How do I fix it?

[It looks like this on IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzlzO.jpg)

[It should be like this(chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEs8U.jpg)

it was defaulted by fusion chart, I didn't change it. when I inspect it, there is a style 'font-family = 'Source Sand Pro'.

[But not working in IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ0pC.jpg)

Comment: We’d need more info to look at this. Can you show how you are setting the font family for example. [link] https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will help you ask a good question.

Comment: I'm not setting or change it, I was trying to give my fusion chart code with baseFont, but it still not working.

Comment: It is possible that your font-family reference is not correct. Do you use font-face?

Comment: Thank you, your answer help me, I downloaded the font 'Source Sans Pro' in google font, then I use @fontface in my CSS, and it works! :D

Comment: Please don't put "closed" in the title of your question. If you find a solution yourself, you're [encouraged to self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Accepting your self-answer is the way of signalling to the system that you've got a solution that you're happy with.

Comment: Ah, I'm so sorry about this, thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the font, then put @font-face in my CSS and called the font.
it will look like this :

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    src: URL(../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are reports of IE not showing this typeface in other situations see for example https://www.joomla51.com/forum/font-source-sans-pro-not-displaying-correctly-in-internet-explorer-11

This site suggests that the browser having tracking protection enabled causes the problem.

Do you have tracking protection turned on in IE11? Try turning it off, and also try Edge if available. I believe MS turned on tracking protection by default on Edge fairly recently, I don't know what (if anything) they have done with IE.

And/or try turning tracking protection on in another browser and see if the font is still being picked up.

Comment: I already found the answer, I download the font from google font and put @font-face in my CSS and its work, thank you for trying to help me :D 
(i checked my ie11 and I found that tracking protection was disabled all of the time)